# how do i write a new row after reading each file?

Tags: python, csv, gis, kml

I would like to write a new row after reading each file. This is from KML to CSV.

At the of the day:
 - Each file should write the values into columns
 - New row for each kml file

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
import glob

def process_coordinate_string(str):

    comma_split = str.split(',')
    return [comma_split[1].strip(), comma_split[0].strip()]


def main():
    """
    Open the KML. Read the KML. Open a CSV file. Process a coordinate string to be a CSV row.
    """

    files = []
    for i in os.listdir('<dir>'):
        if i.endswith('.kml'):
            with open(i, 'r') as f:
                s = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')
                with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
                    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,lineterminator='')
                    for names in s.find_all('name',):
                        writer.writerow(names)

                    for coords in s.find_all('coordinates'):
                        writer.writerow(process_coordinate_string(coords.string))



main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
with open('out.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
```

instead of

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
import glob

def process_coordinate_string(str):

    comma_split = str.split(',')
    return [comma_split[1].strip(), comma_split[0].strip()]


def main():
    """
    Open the KML. Read the KML. Open a CSV file. Process a coordinate string to be a CSV row.
    """

    files = []
    for i in os.listdir('.'):
        if i.endswith('.kml'):
            with open(i, 'r') as f:
                s = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')
                with open('out.csv', 'a',) as csvfile:
                    writer = csv.writer(csvfile,lineterminator='')
                    for names in s.find_all('name',):
                        writer.writerow(names)

                    for coords in s.find_all('coordinates'):
                        writer.writerow(process_coordinate_string(coords.string))

                        print(dir(writer))
                    writer.writerow("\n")



main()
```

Comment: This gives me everything a new row. Instead I want this: For e.g. 1.kml all values 1  row, multiple columns. 2.kml row 2, multiple columns

Comment: Yes, thank you! Voted for you!